# How can I prevent my bitmaps from flickering when i release them from dragging?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, bitmap, panel

I am creating my own app in Winforms where I want to be able to create a map and put icons on it. Those icons will reveal information when clicked. The map is a simple image and the icons are bitmaps. The user can drag an icon onto the map, and afterwards drag it again or remove it.

The problem is that when I drag the icon (a bitmap) and release it, it will flicker for a moment. This will happen regardless of the speed, and regardless of wether it is the very first placement of the icon.

My repo for the code: https://github.com/Foxion7/MapMarker

A screenshot of the panels, icons etc.: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFhKG.jpg To the right is the icon you can click to drag a new icon to the map.

I have already tried using Images with transparancy (didnt work for issues unrelated to the flicker), doublebuffering, checking excessive use of Invalidate().

I would also appreciate advice on other ways besides bitmaps and multiple panels to perhaps circumvent the issue, but I've gotten pretty far with this so far.

Below is an excerpt for the 'in-panel' moving of an icon.

```
    // Selecting an existing icon. 
    private void mapPictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Icon selectedIcon = map.CheckCollision(e.Location);
        if (selectedIcon != null)
        {
            SelectIcon(selectedIcon);
            currentOffset = new Point((e.X - selectedIcon.center.X) * -1, (e.Y - selectedIcon.center.Y) * -1);
            holdingAnIcon = true;
        }
    }

    // Only hides icon on old position when you start dragging to prevent flashing.
    private void mapPictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (holdingAnIcon)
        {
            if(oneTimePerMoveActionsDone)
            {
                selectedIcon.hidden = true;
                mapPictureBox.Invalidate();
                oneTimePerMoveActionsDone = false;
            }
            var dragImage = ResizeImage(selectedIcon.bitmap, iconWidth, iconHeight);
            IntPtr icon = dragImage.GetHicon();
            Cursor.Current = new Cursor(icon);
        }
    }

    // Releasing after dragging an existing icon.
    private void mapPictureBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (holdingAnIcon)
        {
            selectedIcon.location = mapPanel.PointToClient(new Point(e.X - (int)(iconWidth / 3.75) + currentOffset.X, e.Y + iconHeight / 5 + currentOffset.Y));
            selectedIcon.UpdateCenterPosition();
            selectedIcon.hidden = false;
            holdingAnIcon = false;
            oneTimePerMoveActionsDone = true;

            mapPictureBox.Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

The flicker (almost always) happens on release of the mousebutton. There is only a very tiny chance the flicker doesn't appear sometimes.

Comment: If you are not doing any drawing why do any Invalidate?

Comment: Well, i am drawing the icons

Comment: Can you show the Paint code? Or are you just loading icons to the pboxes? What happends when you don't Invalidate?

Comment: If I dont invalidate, I can place an icon but if I ever move it again, it will stay at its current position. I posted my repo so if you'd like to try, you can. Below is some draw code:

Comment: `if (selected)
                {
                    g.DrawImage(bitmap_selected, location.X, location.Y);
                }
                else
                {
                    g.DrawImage(bitmap, location.X, location.Y);
                }`

Comment: PictureBoxes are doublebuffered, so there ought not to be any flicker. As you invalidate in the move you won't need to do it again in the mouseUp. Can't look at your code atm, though..